# CMS for Django when upgrading app from 1.5.5 to 1.7.1

Tags: django, content-management-system, django-cms, django-1.5, django-1.7

I have a huge... challenge in front of me. For about a week or two I've been migrating 1.5.5 django project to 1.7.1. A huge jump, many deprecated variables, methods and so on.
In 1.5.5 there were some south migrations done but not everywhere, as it was not implemented from the beginning. So let's say there are no migrations, they have to be created.

Also there is a wish to add a cms to the already upgraded project, but with django-cms-3.0.7 I constantly encounter some issues with migrations, south existing etc.

**Is there a CMS that I can use with this app that won't be bothered by migrations and django version?**

All I want to edit is the static content (text, images, maybe adding videos) before user logon. No integration with models. Just some info pages.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maybe oversimplified solution for this could be [django-front](https://github.com/mbi/django-front). Create your static pages and add the fields you want to edit. You edit it with a wysiwyg editor. I use it for my terms of service/privacy policy.

You will probably be always bothered by migrations and django version when using an app that brings extra functionality, but the apps should not be hard to upgrade and normally they have a warning/walk through when an important change on their arquitecture/functionality has happened.

That being said, i don't think migrations change dramatically now. The change to include them in the django project was an important (and needed) one.

If you want something even more simple (and time resistant) just create a model for your pages and render it on your template:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    html_content = models.TextField()
    image_content = models.ImageField()
```

Register that model to your admin and that should do the trick. For simple applications this may be enough.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working for me. Have a little to configure but you solved my problem.